# align the text to the bottom of the a tag

Tags: html, css

How do I get the text to the bottom of the a tag which is inside the li.

Here is my code

```
<div id="navigation">         
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">redg</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ryer More</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
    </ul>           
</div> ​
```

And css is

```
#navigation { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    clear: both;
    color: #333;
    background: #2b2b2b; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2b2b2b 0%, #171717 49%, #000000 50%, #000000 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
                color-stop(0%,#2b2b2b), color-stop(49%,#171717),
                color-stop(50%,#000000), color-stop(100%,#000000)); 
}
#navigation ul{
    margin:0 auto; width:auto;
    padding:0;
}
#navigation ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    font:12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding:0 25px;
    background:url(images/nav_img.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    height:50px;
}
#navigation ul li a{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    font:12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:50px; 
}​
```

Comment: Do you want to set the text of a tag itself to bottom.Is it?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking... is this it? http://jsfiddle.net/vgEWf/

Comment: @AymanSafadi Exactly the question is bit confusing I think the text of  a tag needs to shifted to bottom.

Comment: @Sowmya Good to hear that.Everytime something helps you , learn from it.All the best:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relative+absolute positioning.

```
#navigation ul li{
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    font:12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding:0 25px;
    background:url(images/nav_img.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    width: 100px;
    height:50px;
}
#navigation ul li a{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    font:12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:50px;

}​
```

You can see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eB7hq/) here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

- Don't set your 'a' elements 'height' explicitly
- Set 'display' to 'block'
- Add padding-top to your 'a' elements to push them down to where you need them